# Magic Link SDK not responding at all in React Native app

Tags: react-native

I'm currently attempting to test out [Magic Link](https://magic.link) in a really straightforward React Native application, as I'm attempting to try it out ahead of implementing in a real app.

Edit - here's the [documentation link](https://docs.magic.link/client-sdk/react-native/get-started).

However, despite installing the SDK and following the documentation, it is not responding... Or even seemingly attempting to do anything. No error appears, it just doesn't respond - so I must be missing something really obvious.

Here's the 'test' component in full (every line):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { Magic } from '@magic-sdk/react-native';

const m = new Magic('API_KEY');

function App () {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

  const onClick = async () => {
    console.log(email);
    m.auth.loginWithMagicLink({ email: email })
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    await m.user.logout();
    console.log(await m.user.isLoggedIn());
  }

  const getMeta = async () => {
    const meta = await m.user.getMetadata()
    console.log(meta);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.view}>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} value={email} onChangeText={setEmail} />
        <Button style={styles.button} onPress={onClick} title="Submit" />
        <Button onPress={logout} title="Logout" />
        <Button onPress={getMeta} title="Get Data" />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  view: {
    marginTop: 300
  },
  input: {
    height: 60,
    width: 300,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'red',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    borderRadius: 10
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: 50,
    marginBottom: 300
  }
})
```

The Magic Link SDK for React Native functions the same as with Web, but it isn't working despite me pretty much using identical code in a practice web app and it functioning exactly as expected.

Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong, and why none of the functions are responding?

As an FYI - the console logs are working... Indicating it's a problem with Magic I think.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing the relayer component, `<m.Relayer />`

[Relevant section in the docs](https://docs.magic.link/client-sdk/react-native/get-started#rendering-magic)

```
function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      {/* Remember to render the `Relayer` component into your app! */}
      <m.Relayer />
    </View>
  );
}
```